# Special Copy Paste in MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I have some word in a table in MS Word. I also have some word that are not in a table but they are organized serially one by one. I want to paste them in the separate rows of the table. But how?

Please check the image for easy understanding:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Select all the cells you want to paste text into with your mouse so that they appear blue, then press CTRL+V with your 4 lines in the clipboard. That worked for me with Office 2010.